# How do I put infowindow contents into a separate `div`?

Tags: javascript, cartodb

I'm new to CartoJS. When a user clicks a dot on my CartoDB map, I want the content of the infowindow to appear in a separate `div` on the web page.

How do I do this with CartoDB/JS?

Answer (score 0):

you could use what we call an Infobox. Check this example to see how it works:

http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/b53eaf7427427d3fd974